# What happens if the IRS owe me refund, but I file my taxes after the extension deadline of Oct 15?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, income-tax-refund

What will happen if I overpaid the taxes on the extension form, but failed to file before Oct 15 deadline ?

Do I lose any of the refund ?

Comment: The IRS doesn't send you money until you file a form explaining why they owe you money.

Comment: Will I lose any of the refund ?

Comment: Will you file your tax return within a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: @RonJohn I think the essence of this question is what constitutes a "reasonable amount of time", the OP seems to assume that is the date of the extension deadline. I seem to recall its actually substantially longer.

Answer (score 5):

You will not lose any of your refund as long as you file within 3 years of the date that your return is due.  From the [IRS website](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/dont-lose-your-refund-by-not-filing):

> In most cases, an original return claiming a refund must be filed within three years of its due date for the IRS to issue a refund.
>
> Generally, after the three-year window closes, the IRS can neither send a refund for the specific tax year. nor apply any credits, including overpayments of estimated or withholding taxes, to other tax years that are underpaid.